# How can I refactor this django query to not select each individual object?

Tags: python, sql, django

Here's my view:

```
def rsvp_list(request, id, template="rsvp/rsvp_list.html"):
    rsvp = RSVP.objects.get(id=id)

    return render_to_response(template, {
        'attendees': rsvp.attendee_set.all().order_by('email__first_name'),
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and here's my template:

```
{% for attendee in attendees %}
{{ attendee.email.get_name }}{{ attendee.guests }}
{% endfor %}
```

When the request is run, the template then runs a query for each attendee to get their first and last name (get name just puts the two together). Here's an example query that django fires from the template:

```
SELECT `rsvp_email`.`id`, `rsvp_email`.`added`, `rsvp_email`.`first_name`, `rsvp_email`.`last_name`, `rsvp_email`.`address` FROM `rsvp_email` WHERE  `rsvp_email`.`id` = 1038
```

How can I retrieve the first and last name of each attendee is the first query without looping through it 400 times in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read a bit further in the documentation.

In order to reduce the queries that are going to happen on related object later, just use [select_related](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). So my query becomes:

```
attendees = rsvp.attendee_set.select_related().all().order_by('email__first_name')
```